# Flash Builder 4.5 IFDEF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, conditional-compilation

As there any abilities for IFDEF compiler preprocessing?
So that if it is bin-debug, some lines are in the code, if it is bin-release, those lines disappear from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [conditional compilation](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/conditionalcompilation.pdf) so part of your code can be include/exclude depending on flag value.

Here an example for building a debug/release code : http://www.pixelate.de/blog/debug-and-release-builds-with-as3-conditional-compilation.

And here another example with a video for flash builder 4 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ew6h5iIdue4